# What characteristic length should I use to calculate the magnetic Reynolds number?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetohydrodynamics

I am trying to find the braking torque in an eddy current braking system for the setup shown below. I want to consider skin effect for high speed applications. My approach so far has been as follows:
The total power absorbed by the rotor ($P$) can be found by integrating  $\rho J^2$ over the volume of the rotor,
                         $$ P=\int \rho J^{2} {\rm d}V $$
Current density varying due to skin effect:
$$J=J_0 e^{-t/\delta} $$
where $t$ is the thickness of rotor, $\delta$ is the skin depth and $J_0=\frac{\vec{v}\times \vec{B}}{\rho }$.

The air gap magnetic flux density varies as $\vec{B}=B_0e^{-R_m}(-\hat{k})$,
here $R_m$ is the magnetic Reynolds number, $R_m=\sigma \mu_0 L_c v_c$.

So, for this derivation I need a characteristic length. Should I take it as
$L_c = 2\times {\rm air}\,{\rm gap}$?

[image: Orientation of rotor]

Comment: Have you looked up the definition of Magnetic Reynolds Number? What difficulty are you having in applying it here?

Comment: The only problem I have is what value to consider for **characteristic length** here.

Comment: @KP31 You should edit that additional information into your question, including some discussion of what you've considered so far for a characteristic length.

Comment: I suspect that what length you need to consider depends on what question you are trying to answer by calculating MRN.